# How to cope with 'readonly' and 'selected' attributes in WatiN 2.0 against IE9

Tags: watin

I'm using WatiN for web testing, and am encountering issues caused by the fact that for the 'readonly' attribute of INPUT elements, WatiN is attempting to parse the value as a **boolean**, which as far as I can tell is incorrect, as the attribute should be written as follows:

> <input readonly="readonly" />

When I try to access the `TextField.Readonly` property from WatiN at runtime, an error is thrown because WatiN attempts to parse 'readonly' as a boolean. I also encountered a similar issue with the 'selected' attribute of the `<option>` element.

I find it hard to believe that nobody else has encountered these basic scenarios using WatiN which makes me think I am missing something obvious. Is there a known way to work around these issues or is this a known issue with WatiN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has to do with IE9 showing a page in IE9mode differs greatly from how IE9 in IE8mode (and older versions of IE) behaves. These problems have been fixed in WatiN 2.1

Comment: Thanks Jeroen - I just upgraded to version 2.1 and it has indeed resolved the IE9 issues. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of readonly="readonly" that you mention is definitely correct according to w3c school and it looks like you have indeed found a bug.

Looking at  /trunk/src/Core/TextField.cs in line 57 the code is

```
 public virtual bool ReadOnly
 {
   get
   {
     var value = GetAttributeValue("readOnly");
     return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? false : bool.Parse(value);
   }
 }
```

so you should probably just change it to something like this, although I am not using the fancy ? and : syntax :-)

```
 public virtual bool ReadOnly
 {
   get
   {
     string value = GetAttributeValue("readOnly");
     if (value.ToLower() == "readonly")
     {
       return true;
     }
     else
     {
        return false;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd already spotted the implementation through Reflector, but I'd rather not have to modify the source code if I can avoid it. I was wondering whether this was a known issue or whether I was missing something.