# Selecting Asp.Net DropDownList Value with Watin throws an System.FormatException

Tags: asp.net, select, drop-down-menu, watin

I'm trying to test a asp:DropDownList with Watin, but when I try to select a option from the rendered SelectList it Throws an System.FormatException : String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

My page code is:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TesteSelect._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
   <asp:DropDownList  ID="ddl"
    Width="75px" runat="server">

    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="true" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="false"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Content>
```

And my tests are:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using WatiN.Core;

namespace Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ATest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Should_be_able_to_select_yes_from_ddl()
        {
            using( var browser = new IE())
            {
                browser.GoTo(Properties.Settings.Default.ServerAddress + "Default.aspx");
                SelectList ddl = browser.SelectList(Find.ById("MainContent_ddl"));
                ddl.Option("Yes").Select();

                Assert.That(ddl.SelectedItem.Equals("Yes"));
            }
        }
        [Test]
        public void Should_be_able_to_select_no_from_ddl()
        {
            using (var browser = new IE())
            {
                browser.GoTo(Properties.Settings.Default.ServerAddress + "Default.aspx");
                SelectList ddl = browser.SelectList(Find.ById("MainContent_ddl"));
                ddl.Option("No").Select();

                Assert.That(ddl.SelectedItem.Equals("No"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "No" test pass without problem, but the "Yes" test fails with that exception and this stack trace:

> ATest.Should_be_able_to_select_yes_from_ddl
>   : FailedSystem.FormatException :
>   String was not recognized as a valid
>   Boolean. at
>   System.Boolean.Parse(String value) at
>   WatiN.Core.Option.setSelected(Boolean
>   value, Boolean WaitForComplete) at
>   WatiN.Core.Option.Select() at
>   Test.ATest.Should_be_able_to_select_yes_from_ddl()
>   in ATest.cs: line 16

Taking a look at the source code available here => http://watin.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/watin/trunk/src/Core/Option.cs?revision=1194&view=markup

I can see that the error is happening at this snippet at line 136:

```
...
134             private void setSelected(bool value, bool WaitForComplete)
135                 {
136                     if (bool.Parse(GetAttributeValue("selected")) == value) return;
137 
138             SetAttributeValue("selected", value.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
139                     if (WaitForComplete)
140                     {
141                         ParentSelectList.FireEvent("onchange");
142                     }
143                     else
144                     {
145                         ParentSelectList.FireEventNoWait("onchange");
146                     }
147                 }
```

When I look at the HTML generated this makes sense, since this is what's rendered:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddl" id="MainContent_ddl" style="width:75px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="true">Yes</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>

</select>
```

So it fails to Parse "selected" to a boolean, which makes sense. How can I go through this?

Comment: `GetAttributeValue("selected")` should return `true`. What version of IE do you use?

Comment: I'm using IE9. But the source code is not 'prepared' for 'selected="selected'.

Comment: It is prepared, because of internal behavior of IE. "Proof": your code works OK on my computer with IE 8. **EDIT**: in IE 8 and later it depends of IE "mode". See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536429(VS.85).aspx So yeah - it is a bug in WatiN IMO, but related to some version and modes of IE.

Comment: You should put that as an answer, @prostynick

Comment: Even in IE8 mode I can't get this reproduced with IE8. This must be an IE9 issue which I missed cause all the pages in the WatiN test suite force IE(9) to run as IE8, probably resulting in the old behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in WatiN, it was mentioned  the other day along with the 'readonly' attribute:

[How to cope with 'readonly' and 'selected' attributes in WatiN 2.0 against IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537385/how-to-cope-with-readonly-and-selected-attributes-in-watin)

Assuming that is the case, one solution would be to modify the Watin source in a similar way to the marked answer for that question.  And submit a patch if you can, so it works right for the rest of us too!

Comment: Grant, do you also use IE 9? When `selected='selected'` in IE 7 and 8 `GetAttributeValue("selected")` will return `true`. This is how IE internally works.

Comment: See my comment under the question.

Comment: No, I haven't even used drop-downs, just pointing to a similar answer.  Don't have iE9 installed to try it.

Comment: Yest it has. See my comment under the question and link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536429(VS.85).aspx (paragraph starting with "Internet Explorer 8 or later")

Comment: Thanks, I think I will change the source code and submit as patch.

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:DropDownList  ID="ddl" Width="75px" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Try this and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in WatiN. Internally Internet Explorer before version 8 was returning boolean value when calling [`getAttribute` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536429%28VS.85%29.aspx) for attributes like `readonly` or `selected` even if you've had `selected='selected'` or `readonly='readonly'`:

> Internet Explorer 8 or later. In IE8 mode, the value property is correctly reported as a canonical attribute name. For example,  and  would both set the input text field to read-only. In IE8 mode, the value is evaluated as a canonical value, "readonly". In IE7 and earlier modes, it is evaluated as a Boolean value, true.

As you probably now, IE chooses how to interpret your document using things like doctype etc. What I try to say is, when I ran your code on IE 9, I had the same problem as you. When I run it on IE 8, everything was OK probably because my html was malformed and IE changed its compatibility mode to quirks mode.

You can try setting the registry to force your IE to act like IE 7. Unfortunately, I can't test it right now - I have IE 9 installed on different computer. Have a look [Internet Feature Controls article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [More IE8 Extensibility Improvements article on ieblog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx) and try setting your registry for `iexplore.exe` to 7000.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, this seems to be a bug with WatiN when testing against IE9. As suggested, fixing the code and submitting a patch is probably the best solution, but temporarily you can also set IE9 to run the page under test in Compability View. That worked in my case at least.

Just navigate to the page manually once, click the Compability View button, and IE should remember this for the next time you run your tests.

Comment: And just to have mentioned it: as of WatiN version 2.1.0.1196, this seems to have been fixed. My tests are at least passing, even when IE9 is not in Compability View.